# hide body tag but still show a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#print").click(function(){
        $("body").hide();
        $("p").show();
        window.print();
        $("body").show();            
    });        
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>THIS SHOULD BE PRINTED </p>

<button >Hide</button>
<button >Show</button>
<button id="print">print</button>    
</body>
```

given is a sample code. Clicking on print button should hide body of page except the values inside "p" tags. need help as to how to achieve this ?
is there some way of making "p" tag or "div" tag act as body temporarily ?

Comment: It is impossible to have a hidden element with visible content inside of it ...But why would you want to hide your `<body>` tag in the first place?

Comment: If you do a web search for `media query print example` then you will find many examples of how this can be accomplished, without having to add Javascript code to decide what is shown when printing, because CSS will then do that automatically when the output is being generated for printing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below given function to first hide all child of body tag and then show the required child

```
$("body").find("*").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would structure your application differently as you can't show something contained within the element you have hidden.

```
<body>
    <div id="hide-me"></div>
    <p id="show-me">THIS SHOULD BE PRINTED</p>
</body>
```

and change your logic to something like this...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#print").click(function(){
        $("#hide-me").hide();
        $("#show-me").show();
        window.print();
        $("#hide-me").show();            
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be risky to hide everything in the page. Also, the approach makes you ahve to add the content after hiding the body.

A better approach is to make the content you want come to the front, fill up the whole screen, and hide everything else behind it without deleting.

And it's very simply to do so.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.show-print').on('click', function() {
    $('.print-container').addClass('active-print');
  });
});
```

```css
.print-container {
  position: fixed;
  background: white;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.print-container:not(.active-print) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <p>
          Normal body content
    </p>
    <button class="show-print">Print</button>
    
    <div class="print-container">
      <div class="print-content">
        I'm Print. I'm stronger than BODY!
      </div>
    </div>
```